# Using Django DiscoverRunner with django_hstore

Tags: python, django, django-1.6, unittest2, django-hstore

I have test cases created in Django 1.5 and MySQL. Our team has since moved our application to use Django 1.6 and PostgreSQL with the django_hstore extension (1.2.2 beta).

This was working great until I tried migrating our tests to use the DiscoverRunner test suite.

The problem seems to be that `DjangoTestRunner` would load all the applications defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`, but `DiscoverRunner` no longer loads them.

The error I'm getting is :

```
... lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'HStoreDict'
```

And this is because this line in `src/django_hstore/models.py` isn't getting run:

```
connection_handler.attach_handler(register_hstore_handler, vendor="postgresql", unique=True)
```

What is the best way to go about solving this/ensuring this application gets loaded during my tests? **I've currently hacked around this by doing an explicit import of `django_hstore.models`, and this seems to make the error go away**, but it seems to me there may be a better way to solve this.

---

Dropping in django_hstore 1.2.4 doesn't fix the problem.

With that version I get a similar error:

```
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

Unless I hack in the import `from django_hstore import models as something`. Is there a way to get the app to load without having a superfluous import like this?

Comment: Annnd I just realized that a newer version of django_hstore might help me here ;) I could try that...

Comment: Actually, dropping 1.2.4 in makes my work-around stop working, and doesn't fix the problem. Just changes the error to `can't adapt type 'dict'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is late for me to reply but i am posting this because it may help someone for the further reference. This issue got resolved for me by upgrading django_hstore to 1.4